# Touch ID Authentication alert display everytime in new UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, touch-id

i have used LocalAuthentication in my app for Touch ID authentication but Touch ID alert display in every UIViewController for authentication, so how to call only once in a UIViewController?

Comment: Your question is half clear to me, please share the flow and code which causing this issue. Are you using any third party library for this?

Comment: this is my code which i have implemented in only one viewcontroller but display in every viewcontroller, https://dpaste.de/eNd4 @Hemang

Comment: Is this code written in super class? As you said that, its calling every time in different view controllers?

Comment: only write this code in login controller in viewWillAppear method, but when login complete it again ask for authentication in every viewcontroller.. @Hemang

Answer (score 0):

You just create a `BOOL` variable and set the value is `FALSE` in `appDelegate` and when authenticate in one viewController, update the value of the `BOOL` variable to `TRUE`. In every viewController check the `BOOL` variable wheather it is `TRUE` or `FALSE` and code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple API which've written to ease your usage:

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication 

typealias completionHandler = (evaluationComplete: Bool) -> ()


func showTouchID(Reason reason: String, _ shouldShow: Bool, SuperDone : completionHandler){

    guard shouldShow == true else{
        return
    }

    let bike = LAContext()

    guard bike.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil) else{

        SuperDone(evaluationComplete: false)
        return


    bike.evaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {(_, error) in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        guard error != nil else{
            SuperDone(evaluationComplete: false)
            return
        }

    SuperDone(evaluationComplete: true)
        })
}
}
```

Use it wherever you want to like:

```
showTouchID(Reason: "Are", true){ success in

    if success{

    }

    else{

    }


}
```